# Gerrit with solr: Collection not found: changes_open

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, gerrit, solrcloud

I use Gerrit 2.9, Zookeeper 3.4.5 and Solr 6.0.0 (also 5.5.1, and many others).
When I try reindex Gerrit It crashes with error:

```
[2016-05-16 14:49:43,605] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn : Reading reply sessionid:0x154b93571e4001f, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 5,4  replyHeader:: 5,1035,0  request:: '/clusterstate.json,F  response:: #7b7d,s{104,104,1463388906650,1463388906650,0,0,0,0,2,0,104}
[2016-05-16 14:49:43,668] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn : Reading reply sessionid:0x154b93571e4001f, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 6,3  replyHeader:: 6,1035,0  request:: '/aliases.json,T  response:: s{103,103,1463388906643,1463388906643,0,0,0,0,0,0,103}
[2016-05-16 14:49:43,722] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn : Reading reply sessionid:0x154b93571e4001f, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 7,4  replyHeader:: 7,1035,0  request:: '/aliases.json,F  response:: ,s{103,103,1463388906643,1463388906643,0,0,0,0,0,0,103}
fatal: Collection not found: changes_open
```

i.e. Gerrit can't find Solr collection in Zookeeper, but I created necessary collection and this I see from Zookeeper console:

```
[zk: 127.0.0.1:2181(CONNECTED) 0] ls /collections/changes_open
[leaders, state.json, leader_elect]
```

With the Solr and Zookeeper I just started working, maybe I do not understand some of the basic principles.